# Version of parent object is not incremented if one-to-many relationship of the parent object is modified

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink as a JPA provider. I am facing issue with version attribute not being updated whenever a child is added/removed in parent object.

There is a class Company. The Company class has a property Set. The Company class a version field. Whenever I update any non-relationship attribute, the version field of Company instance is increment. However, if I add an instance of Employee class to one-to-many collection employees, version field of Company instance is NOT incremented. Basically, if a child is added to or removed from parent object, version of parent is not incremented.

```
@Entity
class Company {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   @Version
   private Integer version;
   @OneToMany(mappyedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Employee> employees;
   //
   // setter / getter methods
}

@Entity
class Employee {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "compid")
   private Company company; 
   //
   // setter / getter methods
}
```

Hibernate increments version of a parent object if a child is added to or removed from the parent object.

Should not EclipseLink behave the same way? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default EclipseLink increments the lock whenever any direct field, or "owned" relationship changes.  I believe this is what the JPA spec dictates.  A OneToMany that uses a "mappedBy" is not considered an owned relationship, so does not cause the increment of the version by default.

You can configure this using, (causes any change to any relationship or dependent object to increment version)

```
@OptimisticLocking(cascade=true)
```

You can also use a DescriptorCustomizer to set, (causes any change to any relationship to increment version)

```
descriptor.getOptimisticLockingPolicy().setLockOnChangeMode(LockOnChange.ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks James. Very much appreciate your help.