# How to cascade the update of @Version when you update its children?

Tags: java, orm, playframework-2.0, persistence, ebean

## Problem:

I have a parent class with **@Version** on an attribute **"lastUpdate"** for concurrency checking. This parent class has a **@OneToMany** relationship and when I update its children I would like to update the field "lastUpdate" by itself such as happens when I update other fields.

In **JPA** there is *@OptmisticLocking(cascade = true)* to do this operation, but I couldn't find a similar option for **Ebean ORM** in Play2.

**Important**: There is no CascadeType between the classes.

### Code:

```
@Entity
public class Child extends Model {
  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
  public Parent parent;
}


@Entity
public class Parent extends Model {
  @Version
  public Date lastUpdate;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
}


public class Application extends Controller {
  public void updateChild(Parent p, Child c) {
    ...
    c.save(); // or c.update()
    p.children.set(c); // imagine a real code here updating, adding or removing a child.

    p.update();
    return;
  }
}
```

You can find similar question here:
[Version of parent object is not incremented if one-to-many relationship of the parent object is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721354/version-of-parent-object-is-not-incremented-if-one-to-many-relationship-of-the-p)

Thanks a lot... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged as https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/155

Will be supported in 4.1.1 with markAsDirty() method.

```
p.markAsDirty();
p.update();
```