# How to check if related entites are updated, but "vertically upwards" with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I am creating a RESTful webapp with Spring Boot. 
In `service A` (which is my 'persistance service'), I have a class `Configuration`, which has three attributes: `ConfigurationVehicle`, `ConfigurationChargingStation`and `ConfigurationGlobal`, which all are instances of other classes.

The `Configuration` object is sent to another `service B`, which does some calculations. Everytime one of the three related 'special configs' is updated, I want `A` to automatically trigger and send the `Configuration` object to `B`.

What I want to figure out is how to do that, to maybe have some kind of listener that checks for updates in the three related configs, then looks for the object they're related to, get's that specific object and sends it to `B`. 
Like `cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH` but vertically upwards instead of downwards.

Comment: Sounds like you need a version and change detection on the root object: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724804/496099 ). This forces an update on the config, which would allow update events to be fired that you could use to send out the instance to `B`.  Hibernate/EclipseLink can also use events to detect it: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ but it is more involved and requires model changes to support (though you can add the events to the child subclasses directly).

Comment: @Chris so by adding the @OptimisticLocking() annotation to my "Configuration" class and adding a version, the version increments everytime one of its objects (the other configs) change and then I can implement a listener to the version arttribute to fire the event for `B`?

Comment: Just adding OptimisticLocking to the config isn't enough - it is a starting point but there are other actions required to make sure it is incremented when a Config reference is modified. Within EclipseLink, that is the setLockOnChangeMode setting on Config's descriptor. With pure JPA, you have to manually call em.lock on the config when saving other child nodes. Using event listeners on children to force changes to the parent is provider specific - the JPA spec says not to do it - but also works depending on the implementation.