# JPA: incrementing version when field on related entity changes

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm struggling to get my version field updated when a related entity changes. Here's my code:

```java
@Entity
public class Building implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "ownerObject")
    private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
 
    ...
}
```

My `Room` class doesn't have a "@Version" annotated field. I regard the building *and* its rooms as logically one entity. Hence what I would like to see is that even if only a field on a room changes, the version on `Building` needs to be incremented.

I think, I understand I need to use `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`, right? However, I do not understand **where to put that in an Spring Data JPA context**.

I've tried the following:

```java
public interface BuildingRepo extends extends JpaRepository<Building, UUID> {

    @Override
    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
    <S extends Building> S save(S entity);
}
```

.. but it has no effect. This is possibly not so strange since the [Javadoc for @Lock](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Lock.html) seems to indicate it will only work on query-related methods. I'm thinking there has to be a Spring way of doing this?

Comment: You get increments to a `@Version` property in conjunction with (optimistically) locking the entity to which that property belongs.  If you're not locking your `Building`s when you modify their `Room`s, then you will not see its version increase.  I'm not sure how that fits into Spring, but generally, I would not expect you to get such locking on the non-owning side of a relationship unless the locks were taken out explicitly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, I work in Spring Data. In JPA terms: I never do JPA merge/update on the `Room` entity, only on the `Building` entity. So, I'm thinking I can maybe enforce the version increment, by updating a field on `Building`, say `lastUpdated` whenever I call my `save()` method ?  This will be at the expense of an extra database column.

Comment: I would expect that every time you update (in the persistence sense) a property belonging to a Building itself, **subject to an optimistic locking requirement**, you will get an automatic update of its `@Version`-tagged property.  As I understand it, at the JPA level, that optimistic locking requirement needs to be met by explicit request on a per-persistence operation basis.  I don't know whether there's a way to meet the locking requirement through Spring.

Comment: But if you're contemplating adding a new for-purpose property, then perhaps you could meet your needs with that and your DB's built-in transactions *only*?

Comment: This is not something that can be done automatically if you are saving a room instance directly. The lock mode is done on a query, so you can instrument your room save implementation to call find on the Building using a finder method with the LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT annotation on it, or a query with that passed in as a hint. This should not cause an extra hit the DB if the query is an ID lookup so it can use the local cache, and just cause it to be incremented regardless of any changes being found or made to the building instance.

Comment: If you are saving Building - you should write your own implementation that makes its own determination on what has changed (or use your provider API to figure it out) and then look up the building with the LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT option if you want to increment the version when nothing else on it has changed. Otherwise, some providers have non-JPA solutions such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724804/496099